# CSS in Safari/Windows *only*, possibly to do with overflow

Tags: html, css, safari, css-float

Throughout my site at http://www.chrissansom.net there's a basic layout problem that occurs in Safari/Windows only, not even Safari/Mac - and it's fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera on both platforms as well as in IE (current versions). It may well be something fundamental I'm doing wrong, but if so all the other browsers are very forgiving!

Inside the `<body>`, below a header div, there's `<div id="contentbox">` with no style attributes at all. Inside that there's `<div id="leftmenu">` which is floated left, followed (in the code) by `<div id="rightmenu">` which is floated right, followed in turn by `<div id="maincontent">`, which appears between the two menus. It's styled as follows:

```
div#maincontent {
    margin-left: 200px; /* space for leftmenu */
    margin-right: 200px; /* space for rightmenu */
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
/*  border: 1px solid green; */
}
```

(The border is only there for testing.)

In all those other browsers including, I stress, Safari/Mac and Chrome/both (which shares the WebKit code with Safari, no?) it behaves perfectly, but in Safari/Windows div#maincontent acquires an extra right margin of about 400px. The size of this margin remains constant when I resize the window (until the whole thing gets too narrow).

I've found that if I remove the overflow property the extra margin is gone and it looks right, but this interferes with other elements on various pages, which are pushed down below the left menu, so I'm fairly sure I need it.

Any ideas what might be going on here? Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: "Safari/Mac and Chrome/both (which shares the WebKit code with Safari, no?)"...No, not really. Chrome uses their own *flavor* of webkit..called "Blink"

Comment: Also, Safari for Windows is massively out of date and is not under developement any longer. It's basically a dead browser.

Comment: You probably shouldn't worry about issues in Safari on Windows; it has not been maintained for years. The latest version of Safari on Windows is 5.1.7, whereas Safari on Mac is up to version 9.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to provide an [mcve].

Comment: if you like to solve it, then set a `position: relative` and remove the two margin and voilá!

Comment: Points taken about Safari and WebKit - thanks for enlightening an ignorant Mac user. :-) But Francesco es nailed it. I had a feeling it might be something simple, but didn't realise it would be quite that simple. Brilliant, thanks! Consider the thread closed.

Comment: @Francescoes. - Consider posting an answer so that the OP can accept it and the question won't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can easily solve the problem deleting the margins and setting the position to relative:

```
div#maincontent {
    position:relative;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```